# Controlar sobreposição de imagem e texto HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, imagem

Boa noite, gostaria de saber como controlar a ordem de sobreposição de imagem e texto em html, no script abaixo o texto está acima da imagem, como consigo deixar o texto abaixo da imagem?

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Texto sobre imagem</title>

<style>
#imagem {
width: 200px;
height 200px;
}

#texto {
position: absolute;
margin-top: -40px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
  

<img id="imagem" src="http://mdemulher.abril.com.br/sites/mdemulher/files/styles/retangular_horizontal_2/public/core/salada.jpg?itok=8ViA5vi2"/>
<div id="texto">Texto que fica sobre a imagem</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se abaixo for com sobreposição, use z-index no css.
Quanto mais alto, mais "de cima" a camada dele.
Se o item que deve ficar mais "por cima" for o texto:

```
#texto {
position: absolute;
margin-top: -40px;
z-index:9999;
}
```

Comment: Legal, resolveu o problema, obrigado Vitor Andre!!!